# How to: CSS3 animated Popup bubble and text Fade in effect with Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have developed a CSS 3 animated popup bubble that will pop up above and enlarge. Once the pop up animation gets over, a text that is bound to `$scope` will get displayed with a fade-in effect. It uses *Angular Animate* API.

I am sharing it here so that the code can help out people who are searching for a similar solution. The code will work on Chrome. As for other browsers, I have not tested it.

Comment: This is not a question... This is supposed to be a question... Try rephrasing it like a question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is achieved by following steps,

1. Setting the properties of the pop up box through the CSS.
2. Setting the key frame animations to produce the pop up effect.
3. Calling the `Angularjs` controller to bind the data in pop up.
4. Call `timeout` function to make the text to fade in.

The sourcecode is as follows.

This is the `HTML`

```
<body>
    <div class="bubble"><div ng-controller="Fade" ng-show="bool" class="fade" ng-init="init()">{{data}}</div><div class="arrow"></div></div>
</body>
```

This is the `CSS`

```
.fade.ng-animate {
        transition: 0.5s linear all;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .bubble {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        min-height: 50px;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: #7F7F7F solid 4px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        animation: popup 1.5s;
    }

    .arrow:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -19.5px;
        left: calc(15% - 3px);
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 18px 18px 0;
        border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        animation: arrow 2s;
    }

    .arrow:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -15px;
        left: 15%;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 15px 15px 0;
        border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        animation: arrow 2s;
    }

    @keyframes popup {
        0% {
            top: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        100% {
            top: 0px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    }

    @keyframes arrow {
        0% {
            top: inherit;
        }

        100% {
            top: inherit;
        }
    }
```

This is the `Angularjs`

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('Fade', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.init = function () {
            $scope.data = "This text will fade-in";
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.bool = true;
            }, 2000);
        };
    }]);
```